# Record Track feature in SW Maps does not display or record the track despite showing that it is recording

Tags: mapping, offline, tracking

I am trying to record a track using the 'Record Track' feature in SW Maps on my Android phone. My Recorder Settings for the same are: Min. distance between points = 2m; Min. time period between points = 15 secs; required accuracy = 12m. Upon pressing the Record icon, it shows that it is recording, but I do not see any track visible during or after stopping the recording using the Stop icon. I have also tried to set the required accuracy to its default ,i.e., infinity ∞, but that doesn't seem to work either. My location is correctly displayed, and the Skyplot shows more than 7 satellites in use. Also, I am doing all this offline since my field site has network connectivity issues.
I can't seem to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on SW Maps, having just downloaded it. I'm connecting via Bluetooth to a Juniper Geode, and it almost seems like the Geode is TOO accurate.

According to the SW Maps manual, you can select the accuracy under "Record Tracks", but "If location accuracy is below this value, the location is not recorded." (p.26)

The smallest increment is 5 m.

Therefore, it seems that if the locational accuracy is below 5 m it doesn't record, either tracks or feature points.

This is not helpful.

This app might be fine for just using your device's GPS mapping capability, but most mapping from an Android device or phone is 5-15m.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).